# How does a CPU know the address of any variable?

Tags: c++, assembly, cpu

Say you do:

```
void something()
{
   int* number = new int(16);

   int* sixteen = number;
}
```

How does the CPU know the address that I want to assign to sixteen?

Thanks

Comment: I don't have a clue what you want to know. But probably it's sufficient to say that the C code is transformed into machine code that tells the CPU exactly where the values are located.

Comment: Are you really asking a question whose answer is "because the compiler has the address right there in variable `number`?". Just making sure I understand the question...

Comment: Your question is very confusing, because the answer is "the same way it does for `int number = 5; int five = number;`". Except for where `number` gets its initial value from, these are exactly the same. So, are you asking for where `new int(16)` gets a pointer from?

Comment: It's difficult to know how to answer this; how much do you know about how C++ is translated into machine code?

Comment: [long query about what your question means cut to reduce noise in this echo chamber]

Comment: this is a very simple and very well understood question, I dont understand why everyone is so eager to say otherwise.  The fact that so many dont understand it makes it a very important SO quesiton,  so important that it should have many upvotes and stars, not a vote to close.  yet another case of important questions being closed leaving questions like how do I print from my text editor or how do I run an android simulator on my computer being left open.

Comment: @dwelch: I didn't vote to close, but I considered it.  The problem with this kind of question is it's almost impossible to know where to start when answering it.  Do we need to start from first principles?  What does the OP understand about the C++ compilation model, machine code, CPUs, etc.?

Comment: the new is like a malloc, the address is used to initialize number, then you used that address to initialize sixteen as well.  all your code does, as presented is return the address from the new, the rest of the code will be optimized out.  If you had int * fun { int * number = (int *)5; return(number); } (to avoid being optimized out) the return value would be 5.  easy to see if you compile and then disassemble.

Comment: change the 5 to use your new int (16) line and you can see the compiler generates code to call a function the performs the new malloc, which returns and address, number then gets that address and *number gets the 16.  then whatever you do with number, in my case I return, in your case you assign a second pointer with this address.

Comment: the short answer is new causes a malloc like call to happen the size of an int.  this happens runtime and returns an address.  your code as written then re-uses that address for sixteen.

Comment: if this question were to be reopened or re-asked it would be very simple to show this.

Comment: It's the other way around really - the CPU knows *only* where "it" is stored, so how does anyone know what the thing is called? Well normally you don't, and it doesn't even matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no magic in your example code.  Take this snippet, for example:

```
int x = 5;
int y = x;
```

Your code with pointers is exactly the same - the computer doesn't need to know any magic information, it's just copying whatever's in `number` into `sixteen`.

As to your comment below:

> but how does it know where x or y are in memory. If I ask to copy x into y, how does it know where either of those are.

In practice, on most machines these days, probably *neither* of them will be in memory, they'll be in registers.  But if they are in memory, then yes, the compiler will emit code that keeps track of all of those addresses as necessary.  In this case, they'd be on the stack, so the machine code would be accessing the stack pointer register and dereferencing it with some compiler-decided offsets that refer to the storage of each particular variable.

Here's an example.  This simple function:

```
int f(void)
{
  int x = 5;
  int y = x;
  return y;
}
```

When compiled with clang and no optimizations, gives me the following output on my machine:

```
_f:
 pushq  %rbp               ; save caller's base pointer
 movq   %rsp,%rbp          ; copy stack pointer into base pointer
 movl   $5,0xfc(%rbp)      ; store constant 5 to stack at rbp-4
 movl   0xfc(%rbp),%eax    ; copy value at rbp-4 to register eax
 movl   %eax,0xf8(%rbp)    ; copy value from eax to stack at rbp-8
 movl   0xf8(%rbp),%eax    ; copy value off stack to return value register eax
 popq   %rbp               ; restore caller's base pointer
 ret                       ; return from function
```

I added some comments to explain what each line of the generated code does.  The important things to see are that there are two variables on the stack - one at `0xf8(%rbp)` (or `rbp-8` to be clearer) and one at `0xfc(%rbp)` (or `rbp-4`).  The basic algorithm is just like the original code shows - the constant `5` gets saved into `x` at `rbp-4`, then that value gets copied over into `y` at `rbp-8`.

"But where does the stack *come* from?" you might ask.  The answer to that question is operating system and compiler dependent, though.  It's all set up prior to your program's `main` function being called, at the same time as other runtime setup required by your operating system takes place.

Comment: but how does it know where x or y are in memory. If I ask to copy x into y, how does it know where either of those are.

Comment: Editing answer to address your question...

Comment: Regarding the Stack -- you might also find a more detailed explanation here of interest: http://altdevblogaday.com/2011/12/14/c-c-low-level-curriculum-part-3-the-stack/

Answer (score 4):

The CPU knows because your program tells it.  The magic here is in the compiler.  First I build this program in Visual Studio 2010.

This is the disassembly that it generates (in DEBUG mode):

```
void something()
{
003A13C0  push        ebp  
003A13C1  mov         ebp,esp  
003A13C3  sub         esp,0E8h  
003A13C9  push        ebx  
003A13CA  push        esi  
003A13CB  push        edi  
003A13CC  lea         edi,[ebp-0E8h]  
003A13D2  mov         ecx,3Ah  
003A13D7  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
003A13DC  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
   int* number = new int(16);
003A13DE  push        4  
003A13E0  call        operator new (3A1186h)
```

After the call to operator new, `EAX = 00097C58` which is the address that the memory manager decided to give me this run of the program.  This is the address that will be used whenever you dereference number.

```
003A13E5  add         esp,4  
003A13E8  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0E0h],eax  
003A13EE  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-0E0h],0  
003A13F5  je          something+51h (3A1411h)  
003A13F7  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-0E0h]  
003A13FD  mov         dword ptr [eax],10h  
003A1403  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-0E0h]  
003A1409  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0E8h],ecx  
003A140F  jmp         something+5Bh (3A141Bh)  
003A1411  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0E8h],0  
003A141B  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-0E8h]  
003A1421  mov         dword ptr [number],edx  
   int* sixteen = number;
003A1424  mov         eax,dword ptr [number]  
003A1427  mov         dword ptr [sixteen],eax
```

Here you're just making sure that sixteen is the same value as number.  So now they point at the same address.

```
}
```

You can verify by inspecting them in the Locals debug window:

```
+       number  0x00097c58  int *
+       sixteen 0x00097c58  int *
```

You can do this experiment and step through the disassembly.  It is often very enlightening.